# angular-cli AOT error resolving symbols

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have an Angular2 cli project (cli 1.0.0-beta.21)

It builds and runs fine when using ng build --prod and --dev

But if I try **ng build --prod --aot** i get the following error

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls
>   are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a
>   reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule

[I have looked at this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262) but am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import {
    dnnModId,
    dnnSF,
    dnnPortalId,
    dnnTabId,
    dnnEditMode,
    AuthService,
    DnnService
} from './services';

import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';
...
import { ShiftPartialPipe } from './pipes/shift-partial.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    ShiftEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ...
      HttpModule 
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthGuard,
      AuthService,
      DnnService,
      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
      { provide: dnnModId, useValue: moduleId },
      { provide: dnnTabId, useValue: tabId },
      { provide: dnnPortalId, useValue: portalId },
      { provide: dnnEditMode, useValue: editMode },
      { provide: dnnSF, useValue: $.ServicesFramework(moduleId) }
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

<s>I do import some external values into my app using Opaque tokens like this:</s>

```
export let dnnModId: any = new OpaqueToken('moduleId');
export let dnnPortalId: any = new OpaqueToken('portalId');
export let dnnTabId: any = new OpaqueToken('tabId');
export let dnnSF: any = new OpaqueToken('sf');
export let dnnEditMode: any = new OpaqueToken('editMode');
```

Could that be my problem?

**The problem is this line in my app.module.ts**

```
 { provide: dnnSF, useValue: $.ServicesFramework(moduleId) }
```

which imports a value from the following:

```
 export let dnnSF: any = new OpaqueToken('sf');
```

and I have added the following to my typing.d.ts file

```
declare var $: any;
```

**For context:** this app has to live in a CMS that uses jquery functions for building requests to a backend api for data.  So I need to have that service in my app in order to get the required validation tokens for the api requests. *(I know this isn't ideal but it is necessary.)*

### QUESTION

How can I inject this service into my app in a way that works with AOT?

Cheers

Comment: How is $.ServiceFramework currently being loaded?  If it is by script tag in your HTML and not through Angular, then you might need to set a type definition for it to work correctly.

Comment: @BrandynBayes thanks, I have already added declare var $: any; to my typings.d.ts file.  This is part of the javascript tools built into the cms I am using and that is why I had to wrap my bootrapmodule(appmodule) inside a $(document).ready(function () { platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); }

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Also facing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288117/angular-using-injectiontoken-error

Comment: This version of angular is old. I have angular 4 using the cli and I don't have these issues with AOT