# Angular using InjectionToken error

Tags: angular

We need to inject a value using **InjectionToken**, but we are getting the following error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is ne
>   eded by the template compiler (position 3:12 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol $ in C:/Projekte/Git/KWKPortal/App/src/app/shared/dnn.module.ts, resolvin
>   g symbol AppModule in C:/Projekte/Git/KWKPortal/App/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Projekte/Git/KWKPortal/App/src/app/app.module.ts, reso
>   lving symbol AppModule in C:/Projekte/Git/KWKPortal/App/src/app/app.module.ts

here is how we provide this value to be injected:

```
import { SF, $, dnn } from './shared/dnn.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: SF, useValue: $.ServicesFramework(dnn.getVars().ModuleId) }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is the code of our **dnn.module**:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export let $: any;
export let dnn: any;
export let SF = new InjectionToken<any>('sf');
```

I wonder why this is happening? Is `useValue` not proper for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunally I was able to solve this using using **factory**, here is the code:

```
export function servicesFrameworkFactory() {
  return $.ServicesFramework(dnn.getVars().ModuleId);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: SF,
    useFactory: servicesFrameworkFactory,
    deps: []
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way of fixing this, but this solved the original thread.